How to force a field type to be the same type as another field in generic type in typescipt?
Let say I have that code:
type MyStr = "one" | "two" | "three";

const x: MyType<MyStr> = { master: "one", slave: "one" }; // should compile
const y: MyType<MyStr> = { master: "one", slave: "two" }; // should not compile

My goal is to create a type MyType that force the slave to be the same type as the master.
One solution is to do this:
type MyType<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: { master: K, slave: K }
}[T];

The idea is to create all posibilitties, having all versions:
type MyType<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: { master: K, slave: K }
};
// MyType<"one" | "two" | "three"> = {
//   "one": { master: "one", slave: "one" },
//   "two": { master: "two", slave: "two" },
//   "three": { master: "three", slave: "three" },
// }

And taking that type at index of T gives the one we chose.
This approach works but when having a lot of fields, then typescript server is overloaded and die.
Is there a better option to achieve this?
Of course this is just a demonstration of the problem and my real problem is to create something like this:
type ElementFieldType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  name: K;
  Element: FC<{ value: T[K], onChange: (value: T[K]) => void }>;
}

So I need that K will be forced to be the same type in name and in value of Element, meaning once name have been set to some key, Element is forced to be the type that handles that key

If you don't want to generate every possibility in advance, you need generics. And since generic types don't get their arguments inferred, you need a helper function. And since you can't specify MyStr but have the particular key inferred in the same function, you need a curried helper function. That looks like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Hi, thanks, feel free to post it as an answer, I think it is a good thing to know this trick with a function that returns its argument only for the sake of the type.
But between this and the other approach of creating a record of all possible combinations, I personally prefer the later because its not getting the js involve in the ts stuff.
Since I need the performance, I will take the trick you showed. If there is a way without this spaghetti tricks, it will be awesome.

Your MyType<T> distributes over unions in T, so that MyType<T1 | T2 | T3> is equivalent to MyType<T1> | MyType<T2> | MyType<T3>.  But apparently you have some use cases where this doesn't work for you because the union in T is too large. The particular form of MyType<T> is a distributive object type as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. If you want you could change it to a distributive conditional type instead:
type MyType<T> = T extends unknown ? { master: T, slave: T } : never;
const x: MyType<MyStr> = { master: "one", slave: "one" }; // okay
const y: MyType<MyStr> = { master: "one", slave: "two" }; // error

but if the distributive object type is too much for the compiler, it's not obvious whether a distributive conditional type would help enough.

If you can't afford to pre-compute all the possibilities for a given T, then you will need to add a generic type argument so that only the relevant possibility is computed:
type MyType<T, U extends T> = { master: U, slave: U };

Here T corresponds to your original union, while U is the member you want to support. That lets you write
const x: MyType<MyStr, "one"> = { master: "one", slave: "one" }; // okay
const y: MyType<MyStr, "one"> = { master: "one", slave: "two" }; // error

but now you've got "one" written there inside the type.
It would be great if you could get the compiler to infer that for you, by writing something like const x: MyType<MyStr, infer> = {⋯} or even just const x: MyType<MyStr> = {⋯} but it can't. There's an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#32794 for that, but for now it's not possible and you'd need to work around it.  Currently generic type arguments are only inferred when you call a generic function, so the usual workaround here would be to make a helper function which just returns its input, but which gives you the inference you want.
But even for generic functions, you can't manually specify one type argument like MyType and have the compiler infer a different type argument. It's all or nothing.  TypeScript would need partial type argument inference as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#26242, but again, it's not currently possible and you'd need to work around it. The usual workaround here is to curry the function so instead of <T, U extends T>(m: MyType<T, U>) => MyType<T, U>, you have <T>() => <U extends T>(m: MyType<T, U>) => MyType<T, U>:
const myType = <T,>() => <U extends T>(m: MyType<T, U>) => m;

And then you can specify T and save the result to a new function:
const myTypeMyStr = myType<MyStr>();

And use it:
const x = myTypeMyStr({ master: "one", slave: "one" }); // okay
const y = myTypeMyStr({ master: "one", slave: "two" }); // no error!! 

Wait, it didn't work. Why not?

The problem is that TypeScript is more than happy to infer the union "one" | "two" for T inside myTypeMyStr and therefore inside myType.  The way to avoid that is to tell the compiler that you may infer T from master but not from slave. The easiest way to do that is the NoInfer utility type:
type MyType<T, U extends T> = { master: U, slave: NoInfer<U> };

And now everything else works as expected:
const myType = <T,>() => <U extends T>(m: MyType<T, U>) => m;
const myTypeMyStr = myType<MyStr>();
const x = myTypeMyStr({ master: "one", slave: "one" }); // okay
const y = myTypeMyStr({ master: "one", slave: "two" }); // error


So there you go. It works, but unfortunately the features you'd need to support it seamlessly are not implemented, and the workarounds are somewhat clunky. But that's the best you can do for now.
Playground link to code
